# How can I append a Javascript object to FormData that matches the FormGroup.value type?

Tags: angular, form-data, angular-reactive-forms

I'm sending a multipart/form-data request using Angular Reactive forms. My form looks something like this:

```
public myForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
   name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
   email: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
})
```

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <input type="text" id="name" formControlName="name" required>
   <input type="text" id="email" formControlName="email" required>
   <button type="submit">
</form>
```

Then when I submit the form, I run this func:

```
  public onSubmit(): void {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('userDetails', this.myForm.value);
    formData.append('otherData', {test: "hello"});
  }
```

And that is where I hit an issue. I get a linting error that says:

`Argument of type { test: string; } is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'test' does not exist in type 'Blob'.`

How can I append a JavaScript object to FormData in the same way `myForm.value` is? Another way of asking this question is: what type/class is `myForm.value` returning that FormData is letting it append it?

Comment: Is there a reason you need formdata in the first place? If yes, you’ll need to do a JSON.stringify on your test object..

Comment: @MikeOne yeah, in the real form I'm sending files along so that's the reason for the multipar/form-data. JSON.stringify works alright, but I'm assuming that's not how Angular reactive forms is sending this object considering when I console.log the stringified object and `myForm.value` they look very different

Comment: Even though it looks like object, when sending a form (in whatever way) - there is always serialization to string going on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm getting this correctly but if you could create a single object to contain both the `userDetails` and `otherData` properties and values, you could then try using `Object.entries()`.

```
  public onSubmit(): void {
    const formData = new FormData();
    Object.entries(yourObject).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      formData.append(key, value);
    });

    // At this point,formData should have what you need.
  }
```